# Team Foundation Server - Administration > WIT Editor - How to add a Team field to a Work Item?

Tags: tfs

Using WIT Editor for User Story type, I'm trying to add a control that references a system field showing a choice of Teams configured in the Project Profile.

[image: WIT Editor Screenshot]

If that System field does not exist how could I configure a custom one to have as Allowed Values the configured teams.

[image: Project Teams Configuration Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

@DaveShaw it kind of works the other way round. If you create a field in your Work Item that is a drop down list with your Team Names, and they match the team names that you created then you can change the CommonProcessingConfig.xml file to reflect that you want to use this field as the Team Designator.

1. Add a new field called "MyCompany.Teams" with allowed values of "Team A|Team B|Team C"
2. Create Teams in your Team Project of "Team A|Team B|Team C"
3. Use "witadmin exportcommonprocessconfig" to get your CommonProcessingConfig.xml file
4. Under "CommonProjectConfiguration\TypeFields\TypeField" where the **type** is "Team" change the **refname** to "MyCompany.Teams"
5. Use "witadmin importcommonprocessconfig" to import your new CommonProcessingConfig.xml file
6. Test... lots...

I have created a blog post that walks you though this: [Team Foundation Server 2012 Teams without Area](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/team-foundation-server-2012-teams-without-areas/)

You should then be able to use the custom field to hold the value of Team for...your.. team...

*WARNING: Team: Specifies the field used to associate the backlog and task board pages with a team. This field should remain set to its default value, System.AreaPath.*

This is currently early days for this feature so make sure that you test that it works for you.

Comment: MrHinsh wrote an in depth walkthrough on how to do this http://blog.hinshelwood.com/team-foundation-server-2012-teams-without-areas/

Comment: I believe you can automate the maintenance of the global list by creating an ISubscriber or BISubscribe subscription and a bit of custom code.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, "Teams" in TFS2012 are not part of the Work Item's so are not available for use inside them.

I have looked at all the information on MSDN on teams and checked on my own TF Service account and there is no field I can see with a List of Teams associated with them.

Comment: Thank you, Dave. I switched back to a custom field and hard coded list of Teams.